# Derived functor for of a projective module.

Tags: abstract-algebra, homological-algebra, derived-functors, functors

I'm stuck in the exercise 1 of section 6.6, Derivative Functors of Jacobson's book "Basic Algebra II". It states:

> If $M$ is a projective module, then $(L_0 F)M = FM$ and $(L_n F) M = 0, \, \forall n \geq 1.$, where $L_n F$ denotes the left derived functor of $F$.

My attempt:
Given a projective resolution $(C, \epsilon)$ of $M$, i.e. 
$$ \cdots \to C_2 \overset{d_2}{\rightarrow} C_1\overset{d_1}{\rightarrow} C_0 \overset{\epsilon}{\rightarrow} M\to 0 \quad \quad (I) $$
is an exact sequence and each $C_n, \, \neq 0$ is a projective module. Applyng  the functor $F$ to the complex $C$, we have
$$ \cdots \to FC_2 \overset{Fd_2}{\rightarrow} FC_1\overset{Fd_1}{\rightarrow} FC_0 \overset{Fd_0}{\rightarrow}  0 \quad \quad (II)$$
and for the sequence $(I)$:
$$ \cdots \to FC_2 \overset{Fd_2}{\rightarrow} FC_1\overset{Fd_1}{\rightarrow} FC_0 \overset{F\epsilon}{\rightarrow} FM \to  0.  $$

We also have that $(L_0 F)M = H_0(FC) = \ker Fd_0 \,/\, \text{im}\, Fd_1 = FC_0 \,/\, \text{im}\, Fd_1$ and that $(L_n F)M = H_n(FC) = \ker Fd_n \,/\, \text{im}\, Fd_{n+1}$.

How can I proceed with this question?

Comment: Do you know that (up to natural isomorphism) the values of $(L_{n}F)(M)$ are independent of the choice particular projective resolution of $M$? If so, can you think of a simple projective resolution of $M$?

Comment: Can you resolve $M$ by itself?

Comment: Can you think of a really easy choice of $C_0$ and $\epsilon$ to use?

Comment: @EricWofsey Taking $C_0 = M$, $\epsilon = 1_M$, $C_n = 0, \, n > 0$.

Answer (score 2):

The key idea is that you can use whichever projective resolution of $M$ you want to compute $(L_nF)(M)$.  In particular, when $M$ itself is projective, there's a really easy projective resolution: $$\cdots\to 0\to 0\to 0\to M\stackrel{1}\to M\to 0,$$ with $C_0=M$ and $C_n=0$ for all $n\geq 1$.  Applying the definition, we see that $(L_nF)(M)$ is the $n$th homology of the chain complex $$\cdots\to F(0)\to F(0)\to F(0)\to F(M)\to 0.$$  Since $F(0)=0$, the $n$th term of this complex is $0$ for all $n\geq 1$, and so the $n$th homology is also $0$ for all $n\geq 1$.